# Initialize UIImage doesn't works

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, rotation

```
@IBOutlet weak var Needle: UIImageView!
```

to make rotation. My codes are as follow:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    setanchorpoint()
    var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "arrow")!
    Needle = UIImageView(image: image)
}

@IBAction func hold(sender: UIButton) {
    setanchorpoint()
}

setanchorpoint() {
    self.Needle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat(angle*14.2) 
}
```

When the function is fired under ViewDidLoad, it works fine. However, when the function fired under @IBAction error pop out as unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I have no idea why. can someone help?

Comment: Show us how `Needle` is declared and initialized?

Comment: hi, i have edited my code. Needle is declared as follow @IBOutlet weak var NeedleLabel: UILabel! i did not initialise it, but it still can works when the function is fired from view did load but not button clicked.

Comment: @zellb okay, i have edited my code again, now i initialise with                   var image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "arrow")!
Needle = UIImageView(image: image)

Comment: Are you sure @IBOutlet still has reference to that image in storyboard?

Comment: Yup, i did double confirmed because it works when the functions is fired from ViewDidLoad()